# How to have access on specific folders through FTP?

Tags: ftp

My professor has a homepage on Internet based on HTML. The grad students have specific page for themselves. My professor uses University servers. I'm curious to know how is that possible to give the grant of access to specific folders to each student?

Comment: you will have to create ftp accounts for all students and then you can set permission if your that site hosting provider has this facility.

Comment: are you sure it is ftp and not sftp ?

Comment: This is something that needs to be asked of the IT department. There are, I am sure, security policies in place that govern this. Assuming that the appropriate mechanisms are in place, such as FTP servers and access between the FTP server and web server, then this should be possible. It is technically possible give the technologies, however, it may be that the network topography does not allow it or that policies may restrict some level of accesses. Only your IT department can answer this. Not us.

Answer (score 1):

All this would be is each student having a different user account for adding files to the server. The underlying file transport technology is unimportant as this could be done using FTP, SSH, or even a web portal managed by the university to load files to the server. In effect the same underlying process is used. A directory is created and the student is given a user account and permissions to load files to that directory but are unable to make alterations to other directories through the same file transport technology.